# How to pass rows added client-side in MVC3 webgrid back to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, controller, webgrid

I have a Model that contains some string fields and a List. In the view I use EditFor for the fields, and want to use WebGrid for the List.

Display works fine. But then I use jQuery client-side to let the user add rows to the table generated by the webgrid, which also show up fine on the UI.

However these rows don't appear to be tied back to my model's List upon a submit. In the controller I see that the posted model's string fields contain whatever was entered by the user. But the model's List is empty - it doesn't contain the original values nor the newly added values.

How can I cause the model posted back to the controller to be fully populated, including whatever the webgrid-generated table looks like now, just like fields are?

I see several other questions like this for webgrid on the forum, but none with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are comming from WebForms world. Well this is different in MVC. Here you are back to plain old html and its input fields. No viewstate to hold your rows. Check this link: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx.

Basically you need have consecutive index (or ID) for each row.